# how to make code block evaluating to bool

Tags: c#

i am trying to see if its possible to make a code block that evaluates to a bool (so I can make nice compound logicals). Ie the xxxx in this sample

```
if(a == 42 || <xxxxxxxxx> || p > 2)
```

I know I can put expressions in there like `x>"foo"` etc. But what if I need something with statements like

```
var foo = FiddleFoo(97);
foreach(var f in foo) {
   if (fudge(f) > 42)
      // true
}
// false
```

I know that example could be refactored as a LINQ expression but thats not universally true (or is it - hmm?)

I know I could make a separate function but that seems wrong for a single use thing. I tried to do a lambda type thing (like javascript)

```
if .... (()=>{ stuff returning bool}())
```

but that wont compile

Comment: So you're trying to build an [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that returns a bool? Please rephrase your question, it's hard to make out what you're trying to do.

Comment: i dont beleive i am trying to build an expression in LINQ terms (the link you provided). I am trying to build a self contained set of multiple statement that can be inserted directly into an if (or other place where a boolean is required). Other languages can do it

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I suspect this is the case.  btw, your block of code is equivalent to `FiddleFoo(97).Any(f => fudge(f) > 42)`.

Comment: You have an array of parameters where each parameter has two values (like 'a' & 42) and an operator.  You can make a class that will do the evaluation.

Comment: @JeffMercado re XY. i have a sequence of complex boolx | = c1 && c2 || c3 or similar. Now I find one condition that cannot be represented as simple expression. I just wonder if there is a simplish syntax that allow me to enter more complex logic into that pipeline - seems not.  In fact I ended up creating private function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve a statement to a boolean value you can create an anonymous method and then immediately invoke it.  You got that far, trying to use a lambda.  The difference is that you need to add a delegate context for the lambda to be interpreted properly by the compiler:

```
if(a == 42 || (new Func<bool>(() => 
    {
        var foo = FiddleFoo(97);
        foreach(var f in foo) 
        {
            if (fudge(f) > 42)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    })() || p > 2)
{
    //...
}
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this at all.  You're *much* better off extracting this into a named method, even if you do only use it once, but it is indeed possible.

Comment: aha - the syntax I needed. I am surprised that ()=>{}() didnt work. Ie trying to invoke the lambda directly. And yes you are probably correct - this merely obfuscates the intent.

Comment: @pm100 That doesn't work as there is no way for the compiler to determine what the type of that lambda should be.  You need to use it in a context where the type of that expression is defined.

Comment: the lambda 'return false;' returns a boolean. In general the compiler is excellent at determining the return types of lambdas

Comment: @pm100 Yes, it knows that the return type of the lambda is a boolean.  That still doesn't tell it what the type of the delegate should be though, or even whether it should be a delegate at all (or an `Expression`).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
Predicate<FiddleFoo> fiddleFoo = x => {
    foreach(var f in x)
      if(fudge(f) > 42) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Which turns your code into:

```
if(a == 42 || fiddleFoo(new FiddleFoo(97)) || p > 2)
```

Comment: but thats just a fancy function. The code isnt inline